# Unable to install Ubuntu SDK after upgrade to 15.04 from 14.04

Tags: apt, 15.04, ubuntu-sdk

I recently upgraded from 14.04 through to 15.04 so I could start working on a scope idea that I had. Prior to upgrading, I had installed the Ubuntu SDK and had it installed and partially working - but I was having issues with emulators and compiling.

It was suggested to me that I should upgrade to 15.04, and I had already been planning to do so, so I upgraded through 14.10 to 15.04.

However, along the way, the SDK was removed. I figured this was just a normal part of the upgrade process, I can just reinstall it when I get to 15.04.

Wrong.

When I run the `sudo apt-get install ubuntu-sdk` command, I get this output:

```
$ sudo apt-get install ubuntu-sdk
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 ubuntu-sdk : Depends: ubuntu-sdk-libs-dev but it is not going to be installed
              Depends: phablet-tools but it is not going to be installed
              Depends: qtcreator but it is not going to be installed
              Depends: qtcreator-plugin-ubuntu but it is not going to be installed
              Depends: ubuntu-device-flash but it is not going to be installed
              Depends: ubuntu-ui-toolkit-autopilot but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

I have tried adding the `ubuntu-sdk-team` PPA via `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-sdk-team/ppa`, but that gives me the same error.

Output of `apt-cache policy ubuntu-sdk`:

```
$ apt-cache policy ubuntu-sdk
ubuntu-sdk:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 1.221
  Version table:
     1.221 0
        500 http://mirrors.gigenet.com/ubuntuarchive/ vivid/universe amd64 Packages
```

and `apt-cache policy qtcreator`:

```
$ apt-cache policy qtcreator
qtcreator:
  Installed: 3.1.1-0ubuntu9
  Candidate: 3.1.1-0ubuntu9
  Version table:
 *** 3.1.1-0ubuntu9 0
        500 http://mirrors.gigenet.com/ubuntuarchive/ vivid/universe amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
```

What can I do to fix this?

**EDIT**:

Output from `apt-cache policy ubuntu-sdk-libs-dev`:

```
ubuntu-sdk-libs-dev:
  Installed: 1.221
  Candidate: 1.221
  Version table:
 *** 1.221 0
        500 http://mirrors.gigenet.com/ubuntuarchive/ vivid/universe amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
```

**EDIT 2**:

Output from `sudo aptitude install ubuntu-sdk`:

```
$ sudo aptitude install ubuntu-sdk
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  account-plugin-tools{a} accountsservice-ubuntu-schemas{a} click-dev{ab} 
  click-doc{a} gdb-multiarch{a} libandroid-properties1{a} 
  libcontent-hub-doc{a} libhardware2{a} libhybris-common1{a} libpay2{a} 
  libqmenumodel0{a} libqt5bluetooth5{a} libqt5bluetooth5-bin{a} 
  libqt5declarative5{a} libqt5nfc5{a} libtrust-store1{a} 
  libu1db-qt5-examples{a} libubuntu-location-service2{a} 
  libubuntu-platform-hardware-api2{a} libubuntuoneauth-2.0-0{a} 
  libusermetricsoutput1{a} pay-service{a} phablet-tools{a} python-mock{a} 
  qml-module-qtqml-models2{a} qml-module-qttest{a} qt3d5-examples{a} 
  qtbase5-doc{a} qtbase5-examples{a} qtconnectivity5-examples{a} 
  qtcreator{a} qtcreator-plugin-cmake{a} qtcreator-plugin-go{a} 
  qtcreator-plugin-qnx{a} qtcreator-plugin-remotelinux{a} 
  qtcreator-plugin-ubuntu{a} qtcreator-plugin-ubuntu-common{a} 
  qtcreator-plugin-valgrind{a} qtdeclarative5-examples{a} 
  qtdeclarative5-ubuntu-settings-components{a} 
  qtdeclarative5-ubuntu-thumbnailer0.1{a} 
  qtdeclarative5-unity-notifications-plugin{a} qtgraphicaleffects5-doc{a} 
  qtlocation5-examples{a} qtmultimedia5-doc{a} qtmultimedia5-examples{a} 
  qtquick1-5-examples{a} qtscript5-doc{a} qtscript5-examples{a} 
  qtsensors5-examples{a} qtsvg5-doc{a} qtsvg5-examples{a} 
  qtsystems5-examples{a} qttools5-doc{a} qttools5-examples{a} 
  qtxmlpatterns5-examples{a} thumbnailer-common{a} thumbnailer-service{a} 
  ubuntu-emulator{a} ubuntu-emulator-runtime:i386{a} ubuntu-sdk 
  ubuntu-sdk-libs-dev ubuntu-ui-toolkit-autopilot{a} 
  ubuntu-ui-toolkit-examples{a} ubuntuone-credentials-common{a} 
  unity-plugin-scopes{a} unity-scope-tool{a} unity8-common{a} 
  unity8-fake-env{a} unity8-private{a} 
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  libprocess-cpp-doc{u} libproperties-cpp-doc{u} 
0 packages upgraded, 70 newly installed, 2 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 105 MB/119 MB of archives. After unpacking 287 MB will be used.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 click-dev : Depends: python3-click (= 0.4.38.5) but 0.4.39.1+15.10.20150702-0~461~ubuntu14.04.1 is installed.
The following actions will resolve these dependencies:

     Keep the following packages at their current version:              
1)     click-dev [Not Installed]                                        
2)     qtcreator-plugin-ubuntu [Not Installed]                          
3)     ubuntu-sdk [Not Installed]                                       

     Leave the following dependencies unresolved:                       
4)     libproperties-cpp-dev recommends libproperties-cpp-doc           
5)     libprocess-cpp-dev recommends libprocess-cpp-doc                 
6)     qtcreator-plugin-ubuntu-common recommends qtcreator-plugin-ubuntu


Accept this solution? [Y/n/q/?]
```

**EDIT 3**:
Output from `apt-cache policy python3-click`:

```
$ apt-cache policy python3-click
python3-click:
  Installed: 0.4.39.1+15.10.20150702-0~461~ubuntu14.04.1
  Candidate: 0.4.39.1+15.10.20150702-0~461~ubuntu14.04.1
  Version table:
 *** 0.4.39.1+15.10.20150702-0~461~ubuntu14.04.1 0
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     0.4.38.5 0
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ vivid/main amd64 Packages
```

Comment: I've had bad luck with the PPA, and I generally always advise to do fresh installs when updating between minor releases. However, I have had good luck compiling qtcreator from source, which will at least get you the fundamentals.

Comment: What about `apt-cache policy ubuntu-sdk-libs-dev`? Also, the output for your second command is from the first command.

Comment: @saiarcot895 You're right! O.O Oops. Just updated the question and added the new stuff/updated mistake.

Comment: @RPiAwesomeness: Hmm...I didn't expect that. Are you still getting the error. What if you install `aptitude` and try `sudo aptitude install ubuntu-sdk`? (I find Aptitude's error handling is much better than apt-get's)

Comment: @saiarcot895 Edited my question

Comment: @RPiAwesomeness: Run `apt-cache policy python3-click`. It seems like you have a non-standard version of that package installed. Also, you can try typing in `n` to see other possible solutions aptitude gives you. If there is one that only downgrades `python3-click`, take it.

Comment: @saiarcot895 I've updated my question. I tried pressing `n` and it seems to be working now!

Comment: @saiarcot895 It worked! You should post your comment as answer so you get the bounty! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason `ubuntu-sdk` can't be installed is because there is a higher version of the `python3-click` package already installed than the one required by some dependency, and this version is not from the main repos.

You'll need to downgrade the version of `python3-click` installed. You can do this by either running `sudo aptitude install python3-click=0.4.38.5` or going through the list of resolutions given by `sudo aptitude install ubuntu-sdk` and selecting the one that downgrades the package.

Answer (score 2):

After your last edit, the package `python3-click` blocks the installation of `ubuntu-sdk`. Therefore remove the (manually via deb-file?) installed version and install the version from the Ubuntu repositories.

```
sudo aptitude reinstall python3-click
sudo aptitude install ubuntu-sdk
```